# How to stake EOS to increase the amount of CPU time from a separate account?

Tags: accounts, mainnet, cpu, net

I want to do a transaction in one of my account but it doesn't have enough CPU time. How can I stake more EOS from my another account to this account? I want to stop the delegation as soon as I finish the transaction? Can anyone explain the steps I need to take?(Some tutorials would be the best)

`cleos system delegatebw another_account account_that_needs_help "0.5 EOS" "0.5 EOS"`. I got the transaction hash but the transaction never went through(no record on blockchain explorer).

Answer (score 2):

your cleos command looks absolutely right. 
if your transaction did not appear on the blockchain - may be it's because it was accepted by your node (the one that gave you transaction hash), but was not accepted by any of block producers. why? may be you was on the edge of your CPU time and it was enough to run your transaction on your node, but not enough to run it on BPs. or may be your node is not connected to the network at all. try to run the same command using other node with like 
cleos --url http://mainnet.eoscalgary.io:80 ...

Answer (score 1):

What you have written looks right to me.

The reference for this is:
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/v1.1.0/reference#cleos-system-delegatebw

Something I noticed is that [transferring EOS doesn't always work if you don't specify the correct precision](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/2322). So you could also try delegating at the precision that the EOS supply was created with.